# Reading txt in to an array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have a txt file formatted like this

> Name
>
> Height Litres
>
> Height Litres
>
> Height Litres
>
> Height Litres
>
> Height Litres
>
> Prize

And I have two structures called kennlinie and pumpe

```
struct kennlinie {

        int liter;
        int hoehe;

    };

    struct pumpe {

        char name[20];
        kennlinie pkt[5];
        float preis;

    };
```

I have also a variable `pumpe pump[9]`.

`pump[i].name` should contain the name, `pump[i].pkt[j].hoehe` the height, `pump[i].pkt[j].liter`the litres and `pump[i].prize` the price.

What's the best way to import the data from the txt to an array?

Comment: Use std::string, not char arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ reading from a text file into a array/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172166/c-reading-from-a-text-file-into-a-array-string)

Comment: _"the best way"_ is to search for the tens of times such questions have already been asked, try to adapt some of the code you find, and post here with a specific problem if it didn't work for you. Or just read a C++ book or tutorial, many of which should cover this.

Comment: There are sooooo many similar posts.  Search the internet for "StackOverflow C++ read file struct".  Always search before posting.

Comment: Is there any indication of how many Height Liter rows?  Otherwise, determining the Prize may be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The best method, IMHO, is to have the classes read in their members.  The classes know the member type and quantity.  Research "data hiding" and "encapsulation".

This is accomplished by overloading `operator>>`.

```
class Height_Liters
{
  public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Height_Liters& hl);
  private:
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned int liters;
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Height_Liters& hl)
{
   input >> hl.height;
   input >> hl.liters;
};
```

Now you can do something like this to read a Height Liters row:

```
Height_Liters hl;
std::vector<Height_Liters> database;
//...
  my_data_file >> hl;
  database.push_back(hl);
//...
```

However, since there is no indication of how many rows there are, you may want to read it differently:

```
std::string name;
unsigned int height;
unsigned int liters;
unsigned int prize;
std::getline(my_data_file, name); // read first row
while (my_data_file >> height)
{
  prize = height; // Just in case
  if (my_data_file >> liters)
  {
    Height_Liters hl(height, liters);
    database.push_back(hl);
  }
}
```